# WEB SCRAPING - how to access content rendered through javascript ng-binding?

Tags: python, angularjs, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have tried scraping all of the player stats from

https://www.easports.com/madden-nfl/player-ratings?i=1&s=ovr_rating:DESC&v=true&=undefined

by using Beautiful soup:
blogscraper.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

response = requests.get('https://www.easports.com/madden-nfl/player-ratings/?i=1&s=ovr_rating:DESC&v=true&=undefined')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

posts = soup.find_all(class_='player_rating-value')
print(posts)
```

But it gives me an empty list, or if I tried using

```
posts = soup.find_all(class_='ratings-hub_database')
print(posts)
```

It only gives me the stats up until strength

I have read other solutions that says I need to obtain the XHR data from the "Network" tab but I don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the network tab and press F5 to refresh page. Then Ctrl + F to open search box and enter a player name and press Enter. Look at results returned and you will find the following which returns the stats as json

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

data = requests.get('https://www.easports.com/madden-nfl/ratings/service/data?entityType=madden19_player&filter=iteration:1&sort=ovr_rating:DESC,%20lastName:ASC&limit=25').json()
print(data)
```

---

You could write to csv (note that you need to add your own header ordering)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = requests.get('https://www.easports.com/madden-nfl/ratings/service/data?entityType=madden19_player&filter=iteration:1&sort=ovr_rating:DESC,%20lastName:ASC&limit=25').json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['docs'])
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Info.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

Using csv

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests, csv

data = requests.get('https://www.easports.com/madden-nfl/ratings/service/data?entityType=madden19_player&filter=iteration:1&sort=ovr_rating:DESC,%20lastName:ASC&limit=25').json()
with open("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(list(data['docs'][0].keys()))
    for row in data['docs']:
        w.writerow(list(row.values()))
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I obtained the xhr data as a json file and converted it into a csv but all it returns is the colleges rating combined. What I wanted to obtain was something like this sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ImJhXVMz5hCKsfPs1T_XSphDNLq_a9ihfOUgxIK1H08/edit#gid=1610495809

Comment: you need to loop data['docs'] and extract info of interest. Review the json here: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=78bee097d93448cb82b0a4344df68704

Comment: I managed to find the data and understand it. Thank you so much again! and yes, I'll accept this answer